# Make Webpack bundle a TypeScript app which doesn't use modules

Tags: typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I have to migrate the build process of AngularJS 50k-line app written in TypeScript from file concatenation using Grunt to bundling with Webpack.

The problem is that we don't use modules (imports/exports), there's one giant namespace where all code goes to. Hence Webpack can't include files other then starting one to the bundle.

**The question**: Can I make Webpack to bundle single-namespace app without manually going through code and adding imports by hand? Or somehow optimize that manual process?

Comment: I may be wrong - but as far as I know, webpack makes all its decisions (also about CSS and Images) based on if you `require` or `import` something.  But why do you want webpack if you don't have modules? The typescript compiler `tsc` can also bundle all your separate files into one `main.js` file without modules.

Comment: @Kokodoko I'd like to eventually migrate the app to Angular 5. And it uses webpack to build itself. Not sure if I can combine grunt concatenation and webpack bundling in the same project. That's why I've decided to migrate build process first.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible but if you want an answer here, you might need to provide a minimum code example that represents the problem you have.